# chart.js: how to get x axis value on hover

Tags: chart.js

According to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html), I should be able to get x and y data values on click (or on hover):

```
options: {
        onClick: (e) => {
            const canvasPosition = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(e, chart);

            // Substitute the appropriate scale IDs
            const dataX = chart.scales.x.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.x);
            const dataY = chart.scales.y.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.y);
        }
    }
```

I have an x/y graph (y=height; x=distance) and this method is giving the correct height value, but the x value provided is the index of the data point, not the value of the data itself - e.g. if I have 200 data points with x values between 0 and 42 , x returns a value between 0 and 200, not a value between 0 and 42.

I have tried using the option `interaction mode` 'dataset' and 'point' etc, but that hasn't had any effect.
The tooltip that appears on hover has the correct values.

I can correct the values using

```
realdataX = dataX * maxDistance / numberOfDatapoints
```

but this seems clunky.

Comment: If I'd have to guess (and I have to guess since you haven't shared your configuration) you're using the default (for most chart types)`type: "category"` x axis. For a category axis the indices are the true values, labels are just decoration. One other disadvantage of using category axes with linear data is the difficulty in setting "nice" tickmarks. Compare [this fiddle with category axis](https://jsfiddle.net/oufvwn5a/) with [this one with linear axis](https://jsfiddle.net/oufvwn5a/1/).

Comment: You are absolutely correct as per my question - please add this as an answer. Also, using the `linear` type (and the `maxRotation` you used)  has prettified my chart a lot. Unfortunately, I have now restructured my code and in fact I **do** want to return the index to the datapoints, not the values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fact often neglected that many chart types, including the `line` charts, have their default x
axis of `type: "category"`. In the [scatter charts docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#scatter-chart) we find that the main difference between the scatter chart and the line chart is the default x axis of `type: "linear"` (plus some differences in default styling of lines and point markers).

A category axis has as true numeric values (as those returned by [getValueForPixel](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/classes/Scale.html#getvalueforpixel))
the zero-based indices of the categories. The labels, regardless of whether they are numbers or not, are expected to be and treated
as strings - just decorations.

Using the default category x axis where a linear type would have been more appropriate may lead to other issues, like difficulty in setting "nice" labels and the axis failing to respond to linear axis settings, e.g., `ticks.count`, `ticks.stepSize`.

As we found out in the comments, this was also the source of OP's problem.

Of course, the axis type can easily be changed, using the `scales.x.type` property (`{type: "linear"`}).

Here's a code snippet showing the differences:

```js
const N = 200;
const data = {
    labels: Array.from({length: N}, (_, i)=>i / N * 42),
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: Array.from({length: N}, () => Math.random() * 20 )
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                //type: 'linear',
                ticks:{maxRotation: 0}
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        onClick: (e, _, chart) => {
            const canvasPosition = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(e, chart);
            // Substitute the appropriate scale IDs
            const dataX = chart.scales.x.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.x);
            const dataY = chart.scales.y.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.y);
            document.querySelector('#out').innerText = `x=${dataX} y=${dataY}`
        },


    },
};

const chart = new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);

let linear = true;
const button = document.querySelector('#changeType')
button.onclick = () =>{
    linear = !linear;
    if(linear){
        config.options.scales.x.type = "linear";
    }
    else{
        delete config.options.scales.x.type;
    }
    chart.update()
    document.querySelector('#changeToAxisType').innerText = linear ? 'category' : 'linear';
    document.querySelector('#currentAxisType').innerText = linear ?  'linear' : 'default (category)';
};
button.onclick();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-6HrPqAvK+lZElIZ4mZ64fyxIBTsaX5zAFZg2V/2WT+iKPrFzTzvx6QAsLW2OaLwobhMYBog/+bvmIEEGXi0p1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<span style="font-weight: bold">X axis type: <span id="currentAxisType">default (category)</span></code></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="changeType">Change to type: "<span id="changeToAxisType">linear</span>"</button>

<div style="max-height: 60vh"><canvas id="chart1"></canvas></div>
  
<div>Latest click value coords:<span id="out"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly obtain the data point object, including both x and y values, using the "getElementAtEventForMode method. I can provide an example of this.

In this code, we can first obtain the active data point object using "getElementsAtEventForMode." Then, we can access the x and y properties of that data point. I believe this will provide you with the correct x and y values for the clicked point.

I hope this method resolves your issue. Happy coding!

Comment: Hmmm- the method is actually `getElementsAtEventForMode()` (with a 's') and seems over-complex for my needs. I'll stick with the arithmetic conversion.